# Uploading files to Google Drive using python with Docker - googleapiclient.errors.UnknownFileType

Tags: python, docker, google-drive-api

I am encountering an error when attempting to upload files to Google Drive using the Google Drive API in a Docker environment. The file upload works perfectly fine outside of Docker, but when running the code within a Docker container, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/apis/gtest.py", line 60, in <module>
    media = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=file_path).execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 1143, in method
    raise UnknownFileType(media_filename)
googleapiclient.errors.UnknownFileType: upload/2d0a3e62-f442-4b2f-a816-f00e03a6f4db/someexcelfile.xlsx
```

My overall goal is to upload files to Google Drive, where the file type can be either XLSX or JSONL, depending on the file's MIME type. While the upload works flawlessly when running the code on a Windows machine, the issue arises only within the Docker container.

The provided code performs the necessary checks and generates the correct file metadata. For JSONL files, it sets the MIME type to "application/octet-stream" and uses the **MediaFileUpload** object for the upload process. However, when attempting to upload an XLSX file, the error occurs.

How can I ensure that Docker recognizes the correct MIME type for the file upload, allowing it to work properly within the container?

Here is the code for reference:

```
Here is the code:
import os
from datetime import date
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# Define the Google Drive folder ID
folder_id = 'somegoogledrivefolderid'

# Define the file name with the correct file extension
file_path = 'upload/2d0a3e62-f442-4b2f-a816-f00e03a6f4db/someexcelfile.xlsx'
file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)  # Use the base name of the file path

# Check if the file extension is 'jsonl'
file_ext = os.path.splitext(file_path)[1]  # Extract the file extension
if file_ext == '.jsonl':
    print("The file is a jsonl file")
    # Add your code here to handle jsonl files
else:
    print("The file is not a jsonl file")
    # Add your code here to handle non-jsonl files

# Generate the folder name based on the current date
current_date = date.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
folder_name = os.path.join(current_date, '').replace("\\", "")

# Authenticate and create a Google Drive service
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('scripts/gs_credentials.json')
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

# List folders in the specified folder
folder_query = f"'{folder_id}' in parents and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
response = drive_service.files().list(q=folder_query).execute()

# Check if folder already exists
existing_folder_id = None
for folder in response.get('files', []):
    if folder['name'] == folder_name:
        existing_folder_id = folder['id']
        break

if existing_folder_id:
    print(f"Folder already exists with ID: {existing_folder_id}")
    folder_id = existing_folder_id
else:
    # Create the folder
    folder_metadata = {
        'name': folder_name,
        'parents': [folder_id],
        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
    }
    folder = drive_service.files().create(body=folder_metadata, fields='id').execute()
    folder_id = folder.get('id')
    print(f"New folder created with ID: {folder_id}")

# Upload the file to the generated folder
file_metadata = {
    'name': file_name,
    'parents': [folder_id]
}
media = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,media_mime_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", media_body=file_path).execute()

print(f'Successfully saved the file: {media["name"]}')
```

How can I make docker recognize the mimetype so the upload will work properly?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!!!! I went to where the traceback was in the **discovery** module (googleapiclient.discovery) and started reading some of it.

```
if media_filename:
            # Ensure we end up with a valid MediaUpload object.
            if isinstance(media_filename, str):
                if media_mime_type is None:
                    logger.warning(
                        "media_mime_type argument not specified: trying to auto-detect for %s",
                        media_filename,
                    )
                    media_mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(media_filename)
                if media_mime_type is None:
                    raise UnknownFileType(media_filename)
```

I then tried to find out where media_mime_type came from and found out:

```
media_mime_type = kwargs.get("media_mime_type", None)
```

So I realized it was an argument I can use, so I did this:

```
media = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,media_mime_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", media_body=file_path).execute()
```

and it worked